# Selections in texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting

Is there a way to paint with selections?  I don't see any features with rectangle, circle or lasso tool selection in texture paint mode, so I guess there is an alternative. Is it possible though?

Answer (score 2):

Select what you want in edit mode, then switch to texture paint mode and enable this little button.

[image]

Comment: thanks but what if I don't want to follow the  polygons and paint in any place of the sphere with a rectangle shape?There 's no feature for this, but could I play with some  custom mask or so